# Не понятен где физически находится код после запуска , на window 10, команды docker run -dp 80:80 docker/getting-started

Tags: docker

В  https://docs.docker.com/get-started/
После команды  `docker run -dp 80:80 docker/getting-started` докер запускает localhost порт с сайтом, но остается не понятным где на моем компе физически хранится сам код сайта, как это все работает если кода физически нету  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему не понятно все понятно. На win я докер не люблю, ибо могут быть всякие непонятности, в linux все ок. Но то что вы спрашиваете выглядит примерно так.Docker запускает некую среду, под которую выделяются ресурсы. По сути это некий процесс запущенный в операционной системе.

В Docker есть образы и контейнеры. Образы это как бы, некие диски с данными. Когда вы их запускаете они запускаются в контейнере. Настроено может быть по разному. Файлы могут находится внутри контейнера, или часть из них вынесена в Docker volumes, в как бы разшаренные папки.

Так что если вы запустили контейнер, то файлы хранятся внутри контейнера или в volumes привязанных к контейнеру.

Comment: Образы создают контейнер !
Если кода  физически нету но контейнер работает т.е. localhost показывает, значит код находится в самом образе , следовательно оно скрыто за образом ?

Comment: В образе находится условно говоря ,некое дерево файловой системы. Если например ты скачал готовый образ например mysql с https://hub.docker.com/, то уже внутри этого образа находится файловая система с нужными файлами. Когда образ запускается, то эта файловая система как бы монтируется  в некий процесс операционной системы и запускается становясь контейнером. В docker есть команды например docker exec -it 72ca2488b353 sh, так ты зайдешь в запущенный контейнер, и вводя команды обращения к файловой системе увидишь файлы.Если привинчены volumes то их видно и на машине не заходя в контейнер.